# is freemaker a client side template engine?

Tags: spring-boot, client-side, client-side-templating

I'm developping a web application with spring boot I'm using angularjs for the client side, I found out that thymeleaf is a server-side template engine I can't use it with angularjs. I came across freemaker a template engine but I can't whether it works on the server-side or the client and is it necessary to use templating engine in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not.

from the [doc](http://freemarker.org/):

> Apache FreeMarker is a template engine: a Java library to generate
>   text output...